# How to make unequal height columns with same margins inbetween

Tags: html, css

can anybody please help me, how do I make these unequal height columns with an equal amount of margins in between, and my columns should adjust their height according to the content inside but the margin will remain same, do you know any example so I can foll[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUYWy.png)ow, many thanks

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Your question in its current state shows way too little initial effort. And asking for external resources like tutorials, is considered off-topic here to begin with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use masonry layout as here - https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/

Or search for Masonry layout and you will find what you are looking for.

It is very simple and fits your requirement.